# How can i link queueing lib to a project

Tags: omnet++

I've been trying to use the queueing lib to put down a simple network consisting of a source a queue and a sink for hours, please help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `queuenet` and `queueiglibext` project. They are doing exactly what you want to do.